# FreeBSD ifconfig failed when trying to connect to OpenVPN server

Tags: freebsd, routing, openvpn, ifconfig

I am trying to connect to remote server with OpenVPN client, built into pfSense.

I am failing and inspecting OpenVPN log wich says that (from bottom to top):

```
Exiting due to fatal error
FreeBSD ifconfig failed: external program exited with error status: 1
/sbin/ifconfig ovpnc5 10.11.0.34 netmask 255.255.255.0 mtu 1500 up
do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
TUN/TAP device /dev/tap5 opened
TUN/TAP device ovpnc5 exists previously, keep at program end
OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Options error: option 'route' cannot be used in this context ([PUSH-OPTIONS])
PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 10.10.0.0 255.255.255.0,route-gateway 10.11.0.1,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.11.0.34 255.255.255.0'
SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
[server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]XX.XX.XX.XX:1194
```

as far as I understood, server pushes `ifconfig` command, which fails. When I try to execute it manually, it also fails

```
>/sbin/ifconfig ovpnc5 10.11.0.34 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCAIFADDR): Destination address required
```

does this mean that server sends command with incorrect FreeBSD syntax? Or this incorrect syntax comes from OpenVPN?

How to configure OpenVPN client to ignore such commands?

Comment: Why on Earth have you edited the log to be in reverse chronological order?

Comment: @JdeBP I would never do such thing :) it is displayed this way by GUI

Answer (score 1):

You missed `inet` keyword:

```
ifconfig MYIFACE inet MYIPADDRESS netmask 255.255.255.0 mtu 1500 up
```

And `netmask` can be shortcutted to `inet MYIPADDRESS/24`.

Comment: It's not me who formed the command! How to make it to form correctly?

Comment: If you are talking about OpenVPN, then it should pass these options correctly. The message you are see in the log is not the exact command that is being run.

Comment: It states `external program exited with error status`

Comment: Then the problem lies somewhere else. Try reading OpenVPN logs.

Comment: Isn't it OpenVPN log?

Comment: Can you show your OpenVPN config?

Comment: I can screenshot GUI or say how to find it.